# C# connect to AWS using Rest Api i.e. without aws library

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rest

I need to connect to AWS without using C# library i.e. using only HTTP Rest endpoint so is it possible?
The reason I want to do this because I want to give flexibility to customers to connect to any service, in the case of the library I have to utilize the library code to connect to the relevant services.

And can we create an instance of AWS connection once and use that throughout the session instead of passing token or user name & password in headers again and again?

Here is what I tried using C# AWS library and I need to achieve the same using Rest endpoints.

```
public bool sendMyFileToS3(System.IO.Stream localFilePath, string bucketName, string subDirectoryInBucket, string fileNameInS3)
{
    IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

    TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
    TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();

    if (subDirectoryInBucket == "" || subDirectoryInBucket == null)
    {
        request.BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name
    }
    else
    { 
        // subdirectory and bucket name
        request.BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + subDirectoryInBucket;
    }
    request.Key = fileNameInS3; //file name up in S3
    request.InputStream = localFilePath;
    request.ContentType = "";
    utility.Upload(request); //commensing the transfer

    return true; //indicate that the file was sent
}
```

Comment: C# can make HTTP requests, there are several libraries which can do that - built in and 3rd parties. So yes it's possible.

Comment: With most APIs you have to pass the access token to the API in every request - http is a stateless protocol so there's no link between requests otherwise. Usually you only pass the user credentials once though, in order to obtain the access token. Then you don't have to do that again until the token expires. That's generalised information though. Consult the specific documentation for the AWS API to be certain.

Comment: P.s. "I want to give flexibility to customers to connect to any service"...sure but I sincerely doubt that making your own version of the API client is a really a good way to do that. You will still end up with code quite specific to each API because they are not all the same. And you just add a lot of work for yourself that is already done in the ready made library. I'd only write my own c# client for an API if one didn't already exist. But you must do whatever you think best for you.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I wanted to know if there is a way to connect to AWS services using REST endpoints and exchanging data using json instead of having custom classes, I guess you mean using AWS library is better instead of writing something of our own.

Comment: "I wanted to know if there is a way to connect to AWS services using REST endpoints and exchanging data using json instead of having custom classes"...yes there is. But...that's what the AWS library is already doing...it's just a nice neat wrapper around all those messy HTTP requests. So my point is I don't see why you'd want to write all that again, because you'd probably just end up with something quite similar afterwards - i.e. some methods which make the necessary HTTP calls to AWS, and convert the data between C# objects and JSON.